# Atom - subword navigation key bindings

Tags: atom-editor

In my `keymap.cson` file I have the following:

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-left': 'editor:move-to-previous-subword-boundary'
  'ctrl-right': 'editor:move-to-next-subword-boundary'
```

However, my editor does not pick up these new bindings (even after restarting). Also the default keybindings for these two (`ctrl-alt-X`) does not work either.

I'm using Atom 1.0.2, with all core packages.

Comment: You may have solved this by now but I added another possibility to my answer that may explain why it's not working for you. (This bit me too)

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what I added to my `keycap.cson` file to make this work:

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-left': 'editor:move-to-previous-subword-boundary'
  'ctrl-right': 'editor:move-to-next-subword-boundary'
  'ctrl-shift-left': 'editor:select-to-previous-subword-boundary'
  'ctrl-shift-right': 'editor:select-to-next-subword-boundary'
```

Also realize that `keymap.cson` is in CSON format. Just like JSON, you can't "append" to keys in the file by writing them twice. For example, if you wrote this:

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-left': 'editor:move-to-previous-subword-boundary'
  'ctrl-right': 'editor:move-to-next-subword-boundary'

...later in the file...    

'atom-text-editor':
  'cmd-l': 'go-to-line:toggle'
```

Then your subword shortcuts will be *overwritten* by the go-to-line shortcut. The internal CSON parser will not "merge" the values of the duplicate `atom-text-editor` keys.